# Powershell. Call file from command prompt

Tags: powershell

How can I call this to get it work the correct way.

test.ps1

```
function Check($file)
{

   Write-Output "In function"
   $test = Get-Content -Path $file |ConvertFrom-json

  foreach ($line in $test)
  {

      if($line.1111111111 = "true")
      {
           $line.1111111111 = "false"
           Write-Output "This  is: 1111111111 and is now false"
      }
 

     if($line.1111111111 = "false")
     {
          Write-Output "Inside second"
     }
   }
}
```

settings.json

```
{
  "1111111111": true,
  "2222222222": true
}
```

So what I want is to call this out in powershell somthing like

./test.ps1 Check -file C:\settings.json

But I cant get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Also is there a way to read what the name of the 111111111 without knowing it already as in this case?

Comment: In PowerShell, `=` is an assignment operator, if you want equality comparison operator, then `-eq`

Comment: Dot-source the script file to import the `Check` function definition, then call it as any other command: `. ./test.ps1; Check -file C:\settings.json`

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your doubt:

> Also is there a way to read what the name of the 111111111 without knowing it already as in this case?

You could access the object's [`PSObject.Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members?view=powershell-7.2#psobject) to know it's property names and values as shown below.

As for your conditional statements:

```
if($line.1111111111 = "true") { .. }
# and 
if($line.1111111111 = "false") { .. }
```

You should be aware that [`=` is an Assignment Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#assignment-operators), for [equality comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#equality-operators) you should use `-eq` or `-ceq` (for case-sensitive).

Here is an example of how you could call your script and pass in your Json, in this case, I don't think you need a function for this.

**Note**, this should work if the result of your Json is an array, however if it has nested properties which are *arrays* this would not work correctly.

Using **test.json** as an example:

```
[{
    "1111111111": true,
    "2222222222": true
},
{
    "3333333333": false,
    "4444444444": true
}]
```

You would run the script like this:

```sh
# Assuming script.ps1 and test.json are on the folder where we're located
PS /> $newJson = .\script.ps1 .\test.json

In script
This is: 1111111111 and is now false
This is: 2222222222 and is now false
This is: 3333333333 and was not updated
This is: 4444444444 and is now false

PS /> $newJson

[
    {
        "1111111111":  false,
        "2222222222":  false
    },
    {
        "3333333333":  false,
        "4444444444":  false
    }
]
```

**script.ps1**:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param([string]$file)

Write-Host "In script"
$absolutePath = Convert-Path $file
$json = Get-Content -Path $absolutePath | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($object in $json)
{
    foreach($prop in $object.PSObject.Properties)
    {
        if($prop.Value -eq $true) # Could be reduced to just `if($prop.Value)`
        {
            $prop.Value = $false
            Write-Host "This is: $($prop.Name) and is now false"
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "This is: $($prop.Name) and was not updated"
        }
    }
}

$json | ConvertTo-Json
```